# supply chain security - ways of detecting and deterring compromise at a lower level i.e., hardware class of vulnerabilities

Tags: hardware

Software supply chain focuses on software. How about hardware supply chain security? I refer to Compromise Hardware Supply Chain ("https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1195/003/").

I wish to know how can one detect if one's hardware such as CPU, memory chip has been compromised at the hardware level? Are there ways/tools to do so? e.g., perform fuzzing on the hardware layer.

Also, in related to detecting, how does one deter such attacks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there approaches/mechanism to detect hardware backdoors?](/questions/69398/), [How to detect software and hardware impairment?](/questions/236812/), [Search for military installed backdoors on laptop](/questions/199971/), [How can NSA implants and backdoors be detected?](/questions/57666/). In short: there is no easy, generic and cheap way. If you know what specifically you are looking for it might be better, but typically still not easy and cheap.

Comment: Deterrence is not related to detection ... Those are different concepts. And with most of your questions on deterrence, you need to ask something more focused and not opinion-based (i.e. one can't know what might deter a determined attacker),